# Página no encontrada - Error 404 - PHP

Tags: php, error404

Tengo un **proyecto/página web** guardada en una carpeta dentro de **xampp/htdocs/daw/** para realizar las pruebas y funcionamiento oportuno.

Quisiera saber que ocurriría si inserto una **URL incorrecta** o unos datos erróneos, ¿cascaría la página? ¿a dónde me redigiriría? etc...

**Dispongo de un fichero error404.php para el caso: "Página no encontrada".**

Imaginad que inserto:

1. http://localhost:8081/daw/casa.php --> NO existe --> error404.php
2. http://localhost:8081/daw/iniciar_sesion_cliente.php --> Si existe
3. http://localhost:8081/daw/iniciar_sesion_cliente234234.php --> NO
           existe --> error404.php

¿Debo analizar todos los archivos uno a uno, o existe un directorio o fichero global donde poner la dirección "error404.php" en caso de que no encuentre la URL?

Ejemplo de ficheros que sí existen y forman parte de la carpeta "daw":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para presentar la pagina error 404 la tendras que configurar en el htcaccess

Comment: ¿Dónde se encuentra ese fichero? ¿Debo añadir la línea: ErrorDocument 404 /paginadeerror.html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El fichero se llama .htaccess ubicado dentro del directorio de donde tienes el sitio **(en caso de no tenerlo puedes crearlo usando un editor de texto -notepad-sublime o cualquiera que uses)**.

Por lo general se coloca dentro de la carpeta C:\xampp\htdocs\misitio.htaccess

Una vez que tienes el control total del archivo .htaccess debes agregar la siguiente línea y guardarlo.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php
```

Otra forma tambien es porner la ruta completa:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://tusitio/error404.php
```

De esta forma cada vez que alguien introduzca un dirección errónea en tu sitio sera redireccionado a la pagina de error. Así tendrás mas control de tu sitio.

**Nota importante: Una vez configurado todo no olvidar de reiniciar el Xampp**.

Comment: Creo haber encontrado el fichero en la ruta: C:\xampp\htdocs\forbidden

Comment: No, estoy desde local... Cuando suba la web a hosting, lo haré desde hosting.

Comment: Lo añadí y no me redigire a donde deseo... El fichero ".htaccess" está dentro de la carpeta "forbidden". El fichero "error404.php" está dentro de la carpeta "daw". Ambas carpetas "daw" y "forbidden" están al mismo nivel. Entonces debe ser... ¿? ErrorDocument 404 ../daw/error404.php

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70900/discussion-between-omaza1990-and-luis-fernando).

Comment: Todo perfecto Luis Fernando.

Answer (score 1):

Al trabajar con `xampp`, debes trabajar con tu carpeta de prueba.

Así que en `xampp/htdocs`, debes meter tu página de error 404 y crear el fichero `.htaccess`

Para crear el fichero puedes usar cualquier editor de texto y poner la instrucción

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error_404.php
```